# .NET How to send value of drop down list item with GET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to send the value of my drop-down-list in my actionlink as GET method.
How can i get the selected value and send it as parameter?

```
@Html.DropDownList(string.Format("User_{0}", item.UserID), ListProvider.GetRoles(roleId), new {  })
@Html.ActionLink("Set", "UpdateRole", "Admin", new { userId = item.UserID, roleId = roleId }, null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make such GET requests with `@Html.BeginForm` instead of Action Link.

In this case form will build all needed parameters for you automatically.

Use

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Set", "UpdateRole",  new { area="Admin", userId = item.UserID, roleId = roleId }, FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.DropDownList(string.Format("User_{0}", item.UserID), ListProvider.GetRoles(roleId), new {  })
}
```

Or

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Set", "UpdateRole", new { area="Admin"}, FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.Hidden("userId", item.UserID);
    @Html.Hidden("roleId", roleId);
    @Html.DropDownList(string.Format("User_{0}", item.UserID), ListProvider.GetRoles(roleId), new {  })
}
```

Comment: hmm. i see and then just have the userID in a hidden field?

Comment: Yes, all 'invisible' information should be stored in hidden fields.

Comment: or you can store it in RouteValues

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("Set", "UpdateRole", "Admin", new { userId = item.UserID }))

Comment: Where is the roleId at?

Comment: So you can choose between hidden fields and RouteData(fourth parameter of BeginForm)

Comment: i see - i try it straight away!

Comment: The "Set" parameter doesnt do anything? by default i think BeginForm uses Post as method? i think i need to set the parameter to get?

Comment: Yep, you should use another constructor

Comment: What will it send the dropdown value as? i need the int from it

Comment: Depends on what have you bind into value at your ListProvider.GetRoles.

Comment: I bind Value = "x" (number)

Comment: im getting this error: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'roleId' of non-nullable type